# What is an "international equivalent" in the sentence

Tags: application, university

I am applying for college in the state, one of the question in the application is "Will you have graduated from high school, earned a GED, or received and international equivalent prior to enrolling at the University of Oregon?".

My question is

1. What is "international equivalent" refer to? For example, is my high school diploma in Taiwan count as an international equivalent?
2. I'm confusing about the or list, whether the question is asking

   A. (have graduated from high school and earned a GED) or (international equivalent)

   B. have graduated from high school or earned a GED or international equivalent

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your second question, and given that you plan on studying in the U.S., as written it is clear that option B is the case (if your source writes good English in any case). You can google “Oxford comma” to see why.

Comment: Please ask one question only.  The second question might be better directed to the English Language Learners site.

Answer (score 4):

> What does "international equivalent" to high school refer to?

The typical American university is not going to know if your local school is "good enough" to be equivalent to US high school.  If you have completed whatever schooling is customary before enrolling in a university in your country, then if you claim it is equivalent to US high school you will very likely be believed.  Do plan to provide a document showing you completed whatever schooling, translated as necessary, in case someone asks for it.

While the vast majority of US university students have graduated from high school, plenty of people get university degrees without graduating from high school.  So this is not a question that needs careful thought.

Answer (score 3):

The wording is there to account for the fact that things that are approximately the same have different names in different countries and cultures. A HS diploma from Taiwan is probably very similar to a HS diploma from the US in that you have studied fundamental things at an appropriate level for someone about 17 years old, give or take a bit.

A list of "equivalents" would be long indeed.

When you apply, someone will look at your transcripts and target any missing pieces, though I doubt they will find any. Good luck.

---

A [GED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Educational_Development) in the US is a "diploma" given to students who have taken some non standard path to achieve what most students learn in secondary school. One can, for example, earn a GED through a set of tests. But that isn't likely to apply to you.

Comment: To be extra clear about OP's question 2, this is B: you need one of 3 possibilities: US high school, US GED, non-US equivalent to US high school.

Comment: For the non-US reader, "secondary school" is the same thing as high school. Usually, people get GEDs when they drop out for some reason but want to finish.